# UITableView multi selection and swipe actions

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView that has multi selection enabled. I have been using the "selection" to actually change the height of the rows, showing extra detail when "selected". E.g.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return (self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.contains(indexPath) ?? false) ? 200 : 92
}
```

This seems to work pretty well. Until I start doing any swipes actions. When I add some swipe actions, the swipe action seems to clear all of my selections. I actually wanted to deselect the one I was swiping, so it would shrink back down. But the clearing of all my selections doesn't seem to trigger any of the normal delegate callbacks. Even though I have `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing` set to true.

Is there a way to do this? Should I skip (ab)using the selection state as a way to indicate whether the row is showing details with a different height or not? Or is there a way to use it in conjunction with the behavior of the swipes being done in "edit mode" and clearing all of my selections?

Comment: Make that an answer if you want some creds @sticker. I ended up doing mostly that and it worked great. Bottom line is, don't abuse the selection states.

Comment: move as you suggess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is using NSArray to store indexPath of selected cells, and base on saved indexPath you can check and do anything you want. another bug may happened in your code is: What happened in the case user make scroll on tableview? Does cell will reuse and lose select state? New cell reuse the old cell with 200 height will has wrong height?